# How to make an animation node particle wiggle?

Tags: particles, animation-nodes

I wonder if it is possible to have an existing particle setup (keyed) and then use an animation particle node that follows those nodes, but with a wiggle effect.

I have been trying particle nodes the whole day now, but with no results at all. The idea is that some object instance would wiggle around (normal) the particle setup.

Comment: AN won't work for keyed particles, as it is not possible to just read data from them with bpy... you will need to use two particle systems and interpolate between them in AN using vector mix node, then add the wiggle

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the particles from an object, each item from that list is an individual particle which you can get the location of by connecting to a particle info node. Then you mix a vector wiggle to the particle location and use that to set the location of an object.

Here I take the original particle z location and mix a wiggle into the x and y location to place an object that follows the particle downwards.

[image: AN particle nodes]

Add that into a loop to repeat for each particle.

Comment: well i see one object (i used cube) woble now, but its only one, and i wonder how to have each particle be followed by a wobling causin.
Also it doesnt seam to follow the particle (some how the cube wobles mostly around 0,0,0 coordinates.